# Comparing to XML node by Node and Print the differences

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

How to Compare to XML Files Node by Node and to print the differences?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below framework for comparing two XML nodes

http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/